# socket programming in ruby without using FTP

Tags: ruby, sockets, ftp

I am trying to connect to a ftp server without using ftp .. and i have small code of     client.rb

Below is the code.

```
require 'socket'  #tryin to connect with socket rather than FTP
hostname = 'xxx.edu' # server name
port = 21 # default port 
a= Dir.mkdir
s = TCPSocket.open(hostname, port) #opened port
line= s.gets
put line
s.close
```

I have two problems
1) when i try to connect to ftp server usually using cmd , it asks username and  password .. but here its not asking me to enter the server

2) how to execute a command like Dir.mkdir or something directly in server ...as seeing the command in client its executing in client itself..doesnt work with puts send or write

HElp me out !!

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you used a ftp module.

However here is a example ftp communication:

```
Answer: 220 ProFTPD 1.3.3a Server (T-Online FTP Service) [::ffff:10.18.66.32]
Command:    USER rahul-insame
Answer: 331 Password required for rahul-insame
Command:    PASS ******
Answer: 530 Login incorrect.
```

The last line would be different if login worked.

Answer (score 0):

i found that the way to do FTP programming without using FTP library would be by using NET::SSH library for executing the commands in server( also for entering credentials which cannot be done using require 'socket' ) and NET::SCP for uploading or downloading files from server.